# Issue with verifying cvc in gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i used my uncle's credit card to signup with google cloud platform for free tier avaliance .It is not verifying cvc/ccv but it charged 50 ruppes for verification then i cancel it and it automatically redirects to project creation and a project also created.After some time it shows in upper part that your project violate our policy and giving a form  documentation for verification.         **country-INDIA, cc-HDFC BANK**

Answer (score 0):

In the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#free-trial) says this:

> After signing up, you might notice a $0-1 transaction from Google, which is a pending authorization request between our billing system and the bank that issued your credit or debit card. Authorizations might be converted to local currency by your bank, and these transactions might appear as pending on your statement for up to a month. Please keep in mind they are authorization requests only, not actual charges.

That means it is not a real charge just a check.

If you have any other doubt about it, talk with your bank or contact to [Google Cloud Billing Support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing)